# Error using NuSOAP webservice client

Tags: php, html, soap, nusoap

I facing the issue of 'HTTP Error: Unsupported HTTP response status 404 Not Found (soapclient->response has contents of the response)' when using NuSOAP in php. here is the code for server:

```
<?php
require_once "nusoap.php";

function getProd($category) {
    if ($category == "books") {
        return join(",", array(
            "The WordPress Anthology",
            "PHP Master: Write Cutting Edge Code",
            "Build Your Own Website the Right Way"));
    }
    else {
        return "No products listed under that category";
    }
}

$server = new soap_server();
$server->register("getProd");

$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

and here is the code for the client request:

```
<?php
require_once "nusoap.php";
$client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/nusoap/productlist.php");

$error = $client->getError();
if ($error) {
    echo "<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
}

$result = $client->call("getProd", array("category" => "books"));

if ($client->fault) {
    echo "<h2>Fault</h2><pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
else {
    $error = $client->getError();

    if ($error) {
        echo "<h2>Error</h2><pre>" . $error . "</pre>";
    }

    else {
        echo "<h2>Books</h2><pre>";
        echo $result;
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had wrong url in 
$client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/nusoap/productlist.php");
I changed it to : $client = new nusoap_client("http://localhost/testcases/nusoap/productlist.php");
 and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Errors due to **response status 404** is usually caused by incorrect url path.